# Unable to display images Firebase Kotlin getting - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, picasso

Few days back, the code is working fine images getting displayed properly ,but when i tried to do testing after a week android studio started displaying error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:332)
    at com.example.project.messeges.UserItem.bind(NewMessageActivity.kt:115)
    at com.example.project.messeges.UserItem.bind(NewMessageActivity.kt:103)
```

I am using Groupie extension Kotlin, below is the code which used to work perfectly

```
class UserItem(val user: User): Item(){
    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var userProfilePicLink: String? = null

        var userProfilePic = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<CircleImageView>(R.id.imageview_new_message)

        userProfilePicLink = user.thumb_image

        viewHolder.itemView.username_textview_new_message.text = user.username


       Picasso.get().load(userProfilePicLink).into(userProfilePic)


        Log.d(TAG, "Profilepic link: $userProfilePicLink")

    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.user_row_new_message
    }

}
```

by remove Picasso i can get links in Logcat but when i enable i get above. What might caused the issue.

Logcat with adding Picasso

```
2020-01-21 17:50:13.439 6157-6157/com.example.project D/NewMessageActivity: Profilepic link: https://url
2020-01-21 17:50:13.452 6157-6157/com.example.project D/NewMessageActivity: Profilepic link: https://url
2020-01-21 17:50:13.461 6157-6157/com.example.project D/NewMessageActivity: Profilepic link: https://url
2020-01-21 17:50:13.471 6157-6157/com.luvpi.luvproject D/NewMessageActivity: Profilepic link: https://url
```

Comment: What the value of `userProfilePic`? Are you sure it is not an empty String?

Comment: i just simply defined findViewById which is CircleImageView, the same code used to work properly so i havent done any changes

Comment: Please respond to my questions from the first comment, so I or other developers can help you.

Comment: Its not an empty string

Comment: Can you add a log statement and provide us the exact value?

Comment: i am loading an image Url from firebase into CircleImageView to display images

Comment: I see that, but again you didn't provide what I have asked.

Comment: log value of userProfilePic de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView{55f6ab8 V.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0900ba app:id/imageview_new_message}

Comment: So you are using a String that is not actually a valid url, right?

Comment: i am not sure that is invalid or not , because i was checking only image url in firebase database that i am matching and moving that url into target Circleimageview. Previously i havent checked becuz the code was working proprely

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is invalid.  The log tells you so:

```
Profilepic link: https://url
```

"https://url" is not a valid URL and is not going to load an image.  Check your source data.

Answer (score 0):

By just replacing parameters i can load pictures.

```
Picasso.get()
        .load(user.thumb_image)
        .into(viewHolder.itemView.imageview_new_message)
```

I am not sure why this works instead of defining val. Can any one please explain the difference between two of them and why this is one is working